# What does the standard mean by "a subsequent condition of that statement"?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

The standard as of N4567 forbids some kinds of re-declaration of a name previously declared in a *condition* as follows—according to the standard(§3.3.3/4):

> Names declared in the for-init-statement, the for-range-declaration, and in the condition of if, while, for, and switch statements are local to the if, while, for, or switch statement (including the controlled statement), and shall not be redeclared **in a subsequent condition of that statement** nor in the outermost block (or, for the if statement, any of the outermost blocks) of the controlled statement; see 6.4.

However, considering the fact that the following code compiles fine,

```
int main(void) {
    if (int i=10)
        if (int i=20)
            ;
    return 0;
}
```

it seems unclear to me what exactly "a subsequent condition of that statement" stands for.

Comment: Perhaps it refers to the situation for `for`: `for(int i = 0; int i = 1;);`. There's a subsequent condition after the initial declaration of `i`. The wording for `if` though, "any of the outermost blocks", indicates that it considers the else-branches of an `if` to be part of that `if`, so I think it may also refer to `if(int i = 1) ; else if(int i = 1) ;`.

Comment: I think it's talking about declaring a name twice in the same condition. Those are two different `if` statements with different conditions.

Comment: Ah, the structure is `if(...) stmt; else stmt`, so I don't think my example with the two ifs matches. "any of the outermost blocks" is clearly intended to refer to `if(int i = 1) { int i = 2; } else { int i = 3; }` and not to `if(int i = 1) ; else if(...) { int i = 2; }` (IMO).

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb I agree the wording is intended for a for statement as you pointed out.

Comment: @Cornstalks that's what I thought when I ran into that paragraph. Indeed, they don't belong to the same statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The highlighted "that" statement means the `if`, `while`, `for`, and `switch` statement that has defined the name, and not the substatement controlled by the condition or the iteration.

This is explained in:

> **6.4/3:** A name introduced by a declaration in a condition (either introduced by the decl-specifier-seq or the declara- tor of the
>   condition) is in scope from its point of declaration until the end of
>   the substatements controlled by the condition. **If the name is
>   re-declared in the outermost block of a substatement controlled by the
>   condition**, the declaration that re-declares the name is ill-formed.

This is why the following statment is valid:

```
if (int i=10)
    if (int i=20)
        ;
```

The compiler analyses the declaration of `if (int i=20)` not as a different condition of the same if-statement, but as a controlled substatement.  And as the second declaration of i takes place in the condition, it is not considered in the outer block of the constrolled statement.

By contrast, the following almost equivalent statement is not valid, as it breaks the outer block constraint:

```
if (int k=10) {
    int k=20;   // <===== ouch ! redefinition in the outerblock 
    if (k)
        cout <<"oops";
}
```

Hence the only case where you can have a "*subsequent condition of **that** statement*" is the `for` statement.  The standandard highlights this special situation, by giving the rationale to the constraint that you've quoted with a clearer wording:

> **6.5.3/1:** (...) names declared in the *for-init-statement* are **in the same declarative-region** as those declared in the condition,

i.e. declaring the same name in the init and in the condition would break the ODR.

Comment: Why doesn't the `if (int i=20)` count as re-declaring the name in the outermost block of the substatement?

Comment: @M.M because when you declare the variable in the condition, it is visible in the condition and the controlled statement, but not outside.  This is why you can't (anymore) reuse the variables declared in the for init ouside the for statment like `for (int i=...) { ... } if (i==...) handle_special_case();` unless you use some non standard extensions that exist on some compilers to support legacy code.

Comment: @M.M [here an MSDN example of extension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84wcsx8x.aspx) related to the limited scope of the variable defined in initialisation/condition